# Identify Runs in R

Tags: r, run-length-encoding

I have the following vector in R:

```
incident <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

Now I would like to get a second vector, that groups the runs together and numbers the **groups** separately:

```
incidentnumbered <- c('FALSE1', 'TRUE1', 'TRUE1', 'TRUE1', 'FALSE2', 'FALSE2', 'FALSE2', 'TRUE2', 'TRUE2', 'FALSE3', 'FALSE3')
```

I already used the `RLE()` function which returned

```
Run Length Encoding
lengths: int [1:5] 1 3 3 2 2
values : logi [1:5] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

but that didn't quite get me to the needed vector yet.
Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I have clearly misunderstood the question, comments above deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your `rle` with `ave` to count the groups

```
r <- rle(incident)
r$values <- paste0(r$values,ave(r$values,r$values,FUN=seq))
as.factor(inverse.rle(r))
# [1] FALSE1 TRUE1  TRUE1  TRUE1  FALSE2 FALSE2 FALSE2 TRUE2  TRUE2  FALSE3
# [11] FALSE3
```

Answer (score 0):

For a logical vector without NAs, use the lengths from `rle` to repeat 1:5 and divide that by two and use `ceiling`

```
x <- rle(incident)$lengths
n <- rep(1:length(x), x)
# [1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5
n1 <- ceiling( n/2 )
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
paste0(incident, n1 )
 [1] "FALSE1" "TRUE1"  "TRUE1"  "TRUE1"  "FALSE2" "FALSE2" "FALSE2" "TRUE2"  "TRUE2"  "FALSE3"
[11] "FALSE3"
```